# PostgreSQL permission denied exception in ADempiere

Tags: adempiere

While running the adempiere, some times I'm getting the following errors. The application will halt the execution with this exception.

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not open file
>   "base/1459687/1472150": Permission denied; State=42501; ErrorCode=0
>
> DB.saveError: DBExecuteError - ERROR: could not open file
>   "base/1459687/1472150": Permission denied

The same permission denied is happening for the server process too, but not all time.

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not open file
>   "base/1459687/1467687": Permission denied; State=42501; ErrorCode=0
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2102)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1835)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:500)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:273)     at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor426.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.compiere.db.StatementProxy.invoke(StatementProxy.java:100)    at
>   $Proxy67.executeQuery(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.compiere.server.AcctProcessor.postSession(AcctProcessor.java:130)
>     at org.compiere.server.AcctProcessor.doWork(AcctProcessor.java:79)
>     at org.compiere.server.AdempiereServer.run(AdempiereServer.java:232)

The client and server logging the same issue. For clients, after restarting the application, the same process is successfully executing and there is no errors in the console.

The file

> base/1459687/1472150

is in the postgres folder. The pg_log folder in postgresql logging the same error as

> GST ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end
>   of transaction block GST STATEMENT:  SELECT Version FROM AD_System GST
>   LOG:  could not open file "base/1459687/1471980": sharing violation
>   GST DETAIL:  Continuing to retry for 30 seconds. GST HINT:  You might
>   have antivirus, backup, or similar software interfering with the
>   database system.

Its Windows server 2008, and I disabled the antivirus(ESET Nod32) in the server. Postgres max_connections = 300. But the connection limit is not crossing during the time of this error. the client is using jnlp client installation. Any kind help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm failed to find the reason of this issue. Anyway I just re installed the java in the server machine and the issue disappeared. I suspect the Validity of the security certificate in the java control panel. The issue was appeared once after the expiry has over.

Answer (score 0):

Method Run on class Adempiere have a keystore validator, if you make the setup build with one keystore configuration you can't change them, otherwise system can't login and the exception appears.